# Ромбовидное наследование и вызов конструкторов для "НЕ-листьев"

Tags: c++, наследование

Вот такое наследование отключает вызов конструкора **1** при вызове конструкоров **2** и **3**:

```
class _1 {};
class _2 : virtual public _1 {};
class _3 : virtual public _1 {};

class _4 : public _2, public _3
{
    _4() : _1(), _2(), _3() {}
};
```

Но возникает вопрос, что если нужно создать объекты **2** и **3**? Им ведь нельзя вызывать конструктор **1**... Возможно ли создание *"НЕ-листьев"* в такой иерархии наследования?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а почему это им "нельзя". все им можно. Просто при данном ромбовидном наследовании, классы 2 и3 "как бы не владеют своей базой и класс 4 беспокоится о создании объекта класса 1. Но если создается объект класса 2 или 3, то тут они сами уже беспокоятся. Или у Вас есть какая то литература/ссылки, где говорится об обратном?

Comment: При виртуальном наследовании механизм создания объекта виртуального базового класса будет различаться в зависимости от динамического типа создаваемого объекта. Вызов конструктора _1 в конструкторах _2 или _3 может игнорироваться.

Comment: Судя по всему, тут произошло дублирование класса `_1` https://godbolt.org/z/jd8dad

Comment: Виртуальное наследование как раз предотвращает дублирование в данном случае.

Comment: Нет дублирования, это просто выравнивание размеров классов до восьми байт происходит.

Comment: ничего там не произошло, там просто у классов _2 и _3 есть вирутальная база в виде класса _1. Пока они живут сами по себе - они включают класс _1 в себя. К тому же фраза "может не вызываться от user7860670 вызывает кучу вопросов.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы, кажется разобрался.